# react-router-config: How to render a grandchild route with {renderRoutes} only onClick

Tags: react-router

I am trying to render a grandchild component only on the click of a button on the child component. Currently, `react-router-config` says that you must include `{renderRoutes}` on the child component, otherwise the grandchild component will not render.

I have tried the way they suggest below but then my grandchild component appears on the same page as my child component.

This is their example code:

```
const Child = ({ route }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Child</h2>
    {/* child routes won't render without this */}
    {renderRoutes(route.routes, { someProp: "these extra props are optional" })}
  </div>
);

const GrandChild = ({ someProp }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>Grand Child</h3>
    <div>{someProp}</div>
  </div>
);
```

This is my render method currently, without the renderRoutes (it changes the URL properly but does not load the grandchild component):

```
editBanner = async (banner) => {
    this.props.store.router.redirect(`/banners/${banner.id}`);
  }

rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style }) => {
    const { banners } = this.state;
    const banner = banners[index];
    console.log('banner: ', banner)

    return (
      <div className="row" key={key} style={style}>
          <div className="title">{banner.title}</div>
          <div className="city">{banner.city}</div> 
          <Button value="EDIT" onClick={() => 
             this.editBanner(banner)}/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Is there a way to wrap my child component's button with `{renderRoutes}` like you can do with `<Route>` and `<Link>`? Or another way that I'm missing completely? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I just had to add `hideLink: true` to my route config, whoops.